# Intermediate table column by ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eHmz.png)

I just started learning Programing, and this is my first try to develop web.

rails5.0.2
ruby 2.4.1

gem 'ransack' 1.8.3

My final goal is create a form that can search menus from drink's quantity.
Without Intermediate table(single table with all column), I made it . However, Intermediate table .......

I have 3 models( Menu, MenuDrink and Drink ).

```
--------- model ------------
 class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :menu_drinks
  has_many :drinks, through: :menu_drinks

  scope :select_drink, -> (drink) {
  joins(:menu_drinks, :drinks).select("menus.*, menu_drinks.*, drinks.*").where("drink_name=?", drink)
  }

  class << self
   def ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
    [:drink]
   end
  end
end

class MenuDrink < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :menu
  belongs_to :drink
end

class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :menu_drinks
  has_many :menus, through: :menu_drinks 
end

------------- schema --------------
create_table "menus", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "menu_name"
end

create_table "menu_drinks", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "menu_id"
  t.integer  "drink_id"
  t.integer  "quantity"
end

create_table "drinks", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "drink_name"
end

------------ controller ------------
class MenusController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @q = Menu.ransack(params[:q])
    @menus = @q.result(distinct: true)
    @option = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
  end
end

------------ index.html.erb ----------
<%= search_form_for(@q, url: menus_index_path, enforce_utf8: false) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :select_drink_quantity_eq, coke %>
    <%= f.select :select_drink_quantity_eq, @option %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I tried to handle this problem using ActiveRecord object at first, but it did not work out. I found scope can solve this problem, so I study SQL and code this.Nothing seemed to work well ......

I really appreciate your support!

Answer (score 0):

you can search menus by drink quantity without using ransackable_scopes but simply using [ransack associations](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#associations) assuming that you just want to display all the menu names that has a certain drink quantity.
 For example if you search 5 this will display all the menus that has at least a single drink with a quantity of 5

```
--------- model ------------


class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :menu_drinks
  has_many :drinks, through: :menu_drinks
end

class MenuDrink < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :menu
  belongs_to :drink
end

class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :menu_drinks
  has_many :menus, through: :menu_drinks 
end
------------ index.html.erb ----------
<%= search_form_for(@q, url: menus_index_path, enforce_utf8: false) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">

    <!-- select the drinks dropdown -->
    <%= f.label :menu_drinks_quantity_eq, 'Select drink' %>
    <%= f.select :menu_drinks_drink_id_eq, Drink.all.collect {|d| [d.drink_name, d.id]} %>

    <!-- search the quantity dropdown -->
    <%= f.label :menu_drinks_quantity_eq, 'Select quantity' %>
    <%= f.select :menu_drinks_quantity_eq, @option %>

    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
-- then looping through the @menus --
<%@menus.each do |menu| %>
  <%= @menu.menu_name %>
<%end %>
```

Comment: really appreciate your support! thank you very much!! I'm sorry I didn't make it clear enough. How to search a specific drink quantity? For example , which menu has coke 5 ? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I updated the answer to have another dropdown where it allows you to search drink as well. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank your for your reply. Genius! Using Group combinator can make it. I never thought about it that way. May I ask one more question? Is it possible to create specific drink amount f.label and f.select( not selecting drink name)?  For example, f.label and f.select that can search only the quantity of coke. Thank you for your kindness and time !

Comment: if I understand correctly you want to have  just a one select box some thing like 'Coke 5' to be  searchable ? if that is the case you are trying to actually search two column values at once with one select box value. it may be possible but it is not programmatically correct. I would be appreciate if you accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Sorry for confusing you. I add image, so please take a look at it. There are multiple dropdown menus that can select quantity. Each dropdown belongs to specific drink. Is it possible to develop it? Sincerely thank you !!